# Minimum number of piece-wise linear components to approximate a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory, spline, linear-approximation

Let $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^p a_i x^i$ be a polynomial of degree $p$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^p |a_i| \leq 1$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

Let $L_n(x)$ denote a piece-wise linear function on $[0,1]$. In other words, for every $L_n(\cdot)$, there exists a partition of unit interval $0=x_0 < x_1 <x_2<\ldots <x_{n-1}<x_n=1$ such that $L_n(x)$ is affine whenever $x_{i-1} \leq x \leq x_i$.

I want to find minimum number of partitions $N^\ast(p,\varepsilon)$ needed for piece-wise approximation of $P(\cdot)$ upto an error of approximation $\varepsilon$ in sup-norm. Equivalently, find minimum $n$ such that one can always find a $L_n(\cdot)$ satisfying
$$
\|P(\cdot)-L_n(\cdot)\|_{\infty} \leq \varepsilon.
$$

Can anyone guide me about how to solve this or point me to relevant references if this has been already solved before? My attempt to solve this problem has been to use linear interpolation between the points $0,\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n},1$ and use that to approximate error. But I am not sure if this is the right way to solve the problem since $L_n(\cdot)$ can have discontinuities.

Comment: I have not tried this myself, but I think the technique described in the following paper, when applied to polynomials, may yield the desired result: Olga Kupriianova and Christoph Lauter, "A Domain Splitting Algorithm for the Mathematical Functions Code Generator". In *48th Asilomar Conference on Signals, Systems and Computers*, Nov 2, 2014, pp. 1271-1275  [(draft online)](http://hal.upmc.fr/hal-01118915/document)

Comment: I wonder whether algorithms for 2D-shape approximation could be adapted for the desired purpose. For example: James George Dunham, "Optimum Uniform Piecewise Linear Approximation of Planar Curves", *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, Vol. PAMI-8, No. 1, Jan 1986, pp. 67-75.

Comment: @njuffa: I think the analysis in the IEEE paper is more algorithmic rather than theoretical. I maybe wrong since I haven't read the whole paper in detail but do they have the explicit characterization of $N^\ast(p,\varepsilon)$, the minimum number of line segments needed?

Comment: I haven't read these two papers in detail either, which is why I didn't post an answer but comments, hoping the pointers might prove useful. I do not see what is wrong with an algorithmic approach, after all that is how minimax approximations are normally generated: with the Remes algorithm. Linear interpolation at equidistant nodes is not going to guarantee that the error is uniformly $\le \epsilon$ for all segments, the number of nodes and the node spacing needs to be adapted depending on the properties of the function to be approximated.